# ASP NET API WEB: Login con tabla en SQL Server

Tags: api, web, login, net

estoy creando una API WEB en ASP.NET con Autenticación y estoy teniendo un par de problemas por si podeis echarme una mano:

- por un lado, tengo una tabla de usuarios en SQL Server, y quiero usarla como referencia para loguear a los usuarios en la API
- por otro, necesito separar los endpoints que requieren autenticación de los que no la requieren, pero no se si se hace en el controlador (ApiController) o en el mismo WebApiConfig.cs

Es decir, que se lo que quiero hacer, pero en .NET no se como hacerlo, por si podeis ayudarme, gracias :)

Comment: También necesitaría que las rutas de los endpoints que requieren login, estén diferenciadas por el id del usuario logueado

Comment: Si sabes lo que quieres hacer pero no sabes hacerlo en la herramienta lo que necesitas es un desarrollador que conozca la herramienta. Un momento! Se supone que es usted es ese desarrollador? Intente algo y formule preguntas sobre aqo que ya haya intentado y que le haya consumido ya algunos dias sin hallar solucion